# Как сделать hr с градиентами на концах?

Tags: html, css

```
  <div class="description_ul">
    <hr>
    <ul>
        <li>Number of pages</li>
        <li>Academic level</li>
        <li>Urgency</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <style>  
    .description hr{
        width: 210px;
        height: 1px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        border: 0;
    }
    .description hr:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 5px;                
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: в версте после ul есть линия. По макету ее концы размыты и сливаются с фоном бекграунда. Как это осуществить?

Comment: это не заказ, не переживайте так ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы использовал для этого псевдоэлемент и градиент.

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
}

ul::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black 25%, black 75%, transparent);
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Или элемент отдельно, например [`<hr>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/hr)

```css
hr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black 25%, black 75%, transparent);
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 150px;">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Если мой код помог, то отметьте его галочкой как правильный. Какой момент нуждается в объяснении?

Comment: да, конечно! У Вас стоит направление - направо, а размытие происходит в обе стороны. Как?

Comment: и еще, если вставляю hr то размытие не симметрично, почему?

Comment: @Vitaliy, потому что градиент симметричный по этому ему нет разница в какую строну быть направленный. Насчёт hr, Вы используйте код который сейчас? Потому что он симметричен, замените в коде `transparent`, допустим на `red` и обратите внимание на то, что он действительно симметричен.

Comment: добавил скрин, hr не симметричен что бы я не менял...

Comment: @Vitaliy, так правильно, у вас `transparent, #fff 5%, #d3d4d7 95%, transparent`, тут второй цвет белый, а должен быть `#d3d4d7`, чтобы быть симметричным.

Comment: теперь разобрался, спасибо! Последний вопрос: hr after должен быть шире hr с градиентами, как это сделать?

Comment: изменение высоты ничего не дает...

Comment: Предлагаю перейти в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123277/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.root{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom, 
      red, 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
    ) 1 100%;
}
```

Comment: простите, вопрос в том что в бордере одна нижняя линия и оба конца размыты

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, да через псевдоэлементы. Но можно попробовать `border-image`.

```css
.test-bottom {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), red, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 / 0 0 4px;
}

.test-top {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), red, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 / 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-bottom"></div>
<div class="test-top"></div>
```

Comment: Вы использовали нижнюю границу, а как использовать верхнюю? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Добавил в ответ